# I need help about TPL practice

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

Is it a bad practice to execute a collection of tasks **in parallel** having some of these tasks a *Parallel.ForEach()* inside and some others a *Parallel.For()?*

Something like this:

```
Task[] tasks = new Task[n];

tasks[0] = new Task(() => { Parallel.For(...) { } });
tasks[1] = new Task(() => { Parallel.ForEach(...) { } });

Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

Comment: What's bugging you? The parallel loops? Or the fact that one is a for and the other a foreach? That code looks perfectly fine.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with tasks in parallel that each spawn other parallel tasks (which is what `Parallel.For` is doing).  It fits very well with certain types of algorithms.

Comment: What's bugging me is what @Servy exposed in his comment. In fact it isn't bugging me but intriguing me. The fact that many of the tasks will spawn other parallel tasks doesn't add a penalty on the  algorithm's running time?

Comment: It's not inherently wrong, in but that's not to say that it's always a good idea either.  What you're asking is the inherent question of "will running these tasks in parallel improve performance" and the answer is, "it depends". There is an overhead associated with creating the tasks, scheduling them, switching contexts, etc.  There is also the advantage of doing more than one thing at the same time if you have multiple processors/cores/hyperthreading/etc.  If each task runs super fast the overhead will probably make it worse.  If each task takes a while you could come out ahead.

Comment: Of course the best way to know the difference is to simply try it with and without parallelization and benchmark the results.

Comment: The idea came to my mind because I've to split the set of objects to analyze in two sets because they implement one of two different interfaces so if I use two separated ForEach(). The second one will have to wait until the first one finish and because the algorithm to analyze each object will be realized sequencially there will be only one core working while analyzing the last object in the first set and the rest of the cores will be idle and that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly not bad practice to use the proper code construct to deal with the proper data.  If you have reason to do a `for` on one set of data and a `foreach` on another then by all means do so.